# The requested URL was not found on this server in Xampp

Tags: drupal, xampp

Xampp is working well,I can access localhost/phpmyadmin and the main page in my Drupal website is working fine when I click the login in the main page I got this error :

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.7 Server at localhost Port 80
```

any help ?

Comment: First thing first, what is your drupal version and what is the baseurl of the website ? And regarding the link to the login page, what is the href (rendered in the DOM output) of that link and does it corresponds to what you would expect ? (bring these details in your question, thanks).

Comment: I have Drupal version : ````drupal-9.2.1````  and the 
baseurl : ````http://localhost/SpeakFreely.com/````   
the login I meant is login to the website so I can mange the content